# eliminar índices automumericos en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

estoy buscando la manera de eliminar los indices que aparecen automáticamente cuando trabajo con DataFrames.

```
             cod_perso
0                32659
1                29945
2               700330
```

La idea es eliminar 0,1,2, pero al no darme el nombre de la columna, desconozco como borrarlo.

Gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: No es una columna. Son los índices que te permitirán (si lo necesitas) referirte a una fila concreta. Los índices de un dataframe no se pueden eliminar, pues es como si pidieras eliminar los índices de una lista, es un mecanismo interno para referirse a sus elementos. Lo que sí puedes hacer es pedir que no los muestre (aunque siguen existiendo), o designar a una columna concreta como índice (en cuyo caso dejará de ser columna, y se usarán sus valores para referirse a filas concretas, lo que implica que no debería tener valores repetidos)

Answer (score 1):

dile a pandas que tu indice es cod_perso

```
df = pd.DataFrame([32659, 29945, 700330], index=cod_perso, columns=['cod_perso'])
```

Comment: esto sería útil para un dataset de tamaño pequeño, pero si es un dataset bastante grande, estoy buscando de limpiar la columna de indices

Answer (score 1):

Usando el siguiente dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    ["32659"], 
                    ["29945"],
                    ["700330"]]),
                   columns=['cod_perso'])
```

Puedo mostrar el contenido si `hide_index()` te dejo la documentación oficial de Pandas al respecto: [pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html)

Por lo tanto la siguiente sentencia:

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

Te mostraría el Dataframe sin el índice:

```
cod_perso
32659
29945
700330
```

En el caso de que quieras persistir el archivo deberías poner como false la propiedad Index. Te dejo el link a la documentación para [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) pero se aplica para los demás formatos.

Por lo tanto con la siguiente sentencia:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Persisto la información en un archivo CSV sin sus índices.